# Switch color statement -

Tags: javascript, colors, switch-statement, drag

I am looking to make a switch statement for my drag function.
Basically want to be able to click one of the four buttons noted below and have it switch the drag & color function to the color of the button.

```
<div class= "buttons">
      <button class= "orange" onclick(o)>08:00-16:30</button>
      <button class= "red" onclick(r)>08:30-17:00</button>
      <button class= "green" onclick(g)>09:00-17:30</button>
      <button class= "purple" onclick(p)>09:30-18:00</button>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript -->

          <script>
        var box;
        var boxArray;
        var backgroundColor;
        var text
        boxArray = [];

        box = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar");
        for ( var i = 0; i < box.length; i++ ) (function(i){
        box[i].onmousemove = function(e) {
        if(e.buttons == 1)
        box[i].style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor, box[i].innerHTML = text, box[i].style.fontSize = "10px", box[i].style.padding = "4px";
        }
        })(i);



         switch {
            case o: {
            backgroundColor = "orange"
            break;
            case r
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You *switch* statement is syntactically incorrect. You need to provide an argument that you want to compare your switch cases to, and within the *switch* statement, you don't use curly braces.

Something like this:

```
switch (color) {
   case "o":
     backgroundColor = "orange";
     break;
   case "r":
     backgroundColor = "red";
     break;
   case "g":
     backgroundColor = "green";
     break;
   case "p":
     backgroundColor = "purple";
     break;
}
```

Notice that "o", "r", "g" and "p" are in quotes, that's because they are string values, if you omit the quotes, like you did in your code example, JavaScript will interpret them as variables, which would just be undefined.

Comment: Good luck. There are some other mistakes you have made in your code, to be honest, a bit too many to address in my answer. For starters, the onclick attribute in the buttons needs to be written like this: `onclick="changeColor('o')"`, there `changeColor` would be the name of a function you call when the button is clicked, and `'o'` is the argument you provide, i.e. the color code

Comment: Hi there, I have worked it out and thanks for your comment & help -

Answer (score 0):

I have just worked this out now myself -

```
      <script>
    var box;
    var boxArray;
    var backgroundColor;
    var text;
    boxArray = [];

    box = document.getElementsByClassName("sidebar");
    for ( var i = 0; i < box.length; i++ ) (function(i){
    box[i].onmousemove = function(e) {
    if(e.buttons == 1)
    box[i].style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor, box[i].innerHTML = text, box[i].style.fontSize = "10px", box[i].style.padding = "4px";
    }
    })(i);

    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    }, false);



    function changeColor(color){
      switch(color) {
        case 'o' :
          backgroundColor = "orange";
          text = "08:00-16:30";
          break;
        case 'r' :
          backgroundColor = "red";
          text ="08:30-17:00";
          break;
        case 'g' :
          backgroundColor = "green";
          text ="09:00-17:30";
          break;
        case 'p' :
          backgroundColor = "purple";
          text ="09:00-17:30";
        }
      }



      </script>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
switch(e.target)
{ 
 case red:
 body.style.backgroundColor="red";
 break;

 case yellow:
 body.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
 break;

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is this supposed to be? Did you actually test it? It's certainly not valid JavaScript.